# GraphQL arguments on sub-fields

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

Is it possible in GraphQL to filter results based on subfields arguments? For example:

```
{
 allNews(id: 999) {
    id
    startDate
    endDate
    newsText(title: "hello", message: "testMessage") {
        length
        disitrubutionDate
    }
 }
}
```

I built the following schema:

```
type news {
  id: Int
  startDate: String
  endDate: String
  newsText: [newsText]
}

type newsText {
  message: String
  title: String
  length: Int
  distributionDate: String
}
type Query {
  allNews(id: Int, startDate: String, endDate: String): [news]
  allNewsTexts(message: String, title: String): [newsText]
}
```

If I change the `type news` to:

```
type news {
  id: Int
  startDate: String
  endDate: String
  allNewsTexts(message: String, title: String): [newsText]
}
```

the data fetcher linked to the allNewsTexts query it's not invoked so the output will be:

```
"allNews": [
        {
            "id": 999,
            "startDate": "2020-02-27",
            "endDate": "2020-02-28",
            "allNewsTexts": null
        }
    ]
```

My java data fetcher simply return the `repository.findAll()` filtered by `id, startDate, endDate`

Comment: "filter results based on subfields arguments" - if you mean to filter subfield results based on subfield arguments then yes, that is definitely possible. You wouldn't be able to filter `allNews` results based on arguments for the `newsText` subfield. And the `null` result indicates that you're most likely not resolving that subfield properly.

Comment: I mean a filtering like the first example. First the news with Id = 999 then the news that have specific title and message. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, the first query is definitely possible and GraphQL allows for that.

Comment: Mh ok, thanks you. Do you have any idea of why it returns null? I noticed that if I do a  post request with only `allNewsTexts(message: "messageTest", title: "titleTest") { length }` then it returns the correct response, but if I run `news(id:5) {allNewsTexts(message: "messageTest", title: "titleTest"){ length }}` it returns null.

Comment: That sounds like the resolver is not doing what it's supposed to and returning a "wrong" response, assuming that the `news` thing with `id` of `5` actually has some data for the `allNewsTexts` with the specified filter properties. There's nothing wrong with your query - it's the backend that's not handling it properly, assuming the data exists and it's supposed to return something.

Comment: I made some correction and now my query return the nested objects(e.g. the news text) but I see that the query allNewsTexts it's never invoked (putted a print in the resolver of allNewsText), it only extract the data, so I'm unable to get the paramters(message and title)

Comment: you can't use query type as other type property

Comment: @xadm Oh ok, it's the same thing I was thinking about... So, what's the workaround to reach my goal? I'm thinking about move all filters on the parent level and query a view that is the join of all the tables (but I think this is an horrible idea)

Comment: this would be good for one reason - only one sql query ....  `allNews` resolver should have a `newsText` field resolver - it should be called with own filter params  - this field can't be returned/defined by first resolver

Comment: Just so I understand, you're looking for something like in the following (second) example right? https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#arguments

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for something like the second example of the arguments section of your link(e.g. I can ask for human with id = 1000 and an height >= x)

Comment: This is definitely possible, I am not sure how `graphql-java` works, but `Node.js` tools definitely provide this ability - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/resolvers/#resolver-function-signature. Something similar should be available on `graphql-java`'s end.

Comment: Similar to this resolver example where you have an `Author` with `posts` - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/resolvers/#resolver-map. But the `posts` resolver signature is `(obj, args, context, info)`. If you were to do something like `author { posts(limit: 100) }`, that number would be available under `args` and `obj` in this case would be the parent object, for example user with ID of 1.

Comment: Yeah I've also read a lot of examples in NodeJS and with Apollo. It would seem that graphql-java does not support this feature. The only thing that comes to mind is something like this: https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/master/data-mapping/ (moving to the parent all sub-filters)

Comment: Ahh I see, that's a bummer if `graphql-java` doesn't support this.